# Minecart ejection and deletion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have made/gathered an elaborate ruse of command blocks to essentially not accomplish my goal correctly. I have an objective "InCar" that tests each player to see if they are in fact in a minecart.

```
/scoreboard players set @a InCar 1 {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable"}}}
```

And then further down the line of chain-conditional command blocks, another check which I now think it also has to be another scoreboard record. Which I haven't tested yet because of my question.

I will just ask how to *only* execute on the one player who is both in a minecart and with a stone block in hand in correct slot of their inventory? Or how to execute on that specific player on just *one* of the scoreboard items? I could go from there maybe.

Currently when 2 people or more are riding carts, they are all ejected and all carts are destroyed (like they should, minus everyone else not holding the stone). I know it is because my code to execute is not "aimed" at the player I want.

CC:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~  /tp @p ~ ~ ~2
/execute @p ~ ~ ~  /kill @e[type=MinecartRideable,r=4]
```

EDIT
Created the InHand scoreboard

```
/scoreboard players set @a InHand 1 {SelectedItemSlot:1,Inventory:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:stone"}]}
```

Then had to create a 3rd scoreboard that basically only scores a point if the player has both other scoreboard items and then activates.

```
/execute @a[score_InCar_min=1,score_InHand=1,score_InHand_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @a eject 1
```

Then cleared all the scores with each command having a "negative" to their "positive" action

```
/execute @a[score_InCar_min=0,score_InHand=0,score_InHand_min=0] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @a eject 0

/scoreboard players set @a InHand 0
```

Then the final command that is working so far.

```
/execute @a[score_eject_min=1,score_eject=1] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[r=2,type=MinecartRideable]
```

I was just tired of googling every step of the way. But I guess I am learning.
I will report back any issues, or updates. Hope this finds someone well.  I don't know if you can just run this and it will work, or if you do actually have to setup the scoreboard items like I did prior to creating the commands..

This is running on a SMP server with Forge and a few mods. Running 1.10.2

2ND EDIT

It worked different this time. It won't delete all the carts not occupied.  But it will still delete ALL occupied carts.. -_-

3rd Edit

I am now using Venya's code to simplify the scoreboard, so my 2 command blocks for score are now.

```
/scoreboard players set @a eject 1 {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable"}},SelectedItemSlot:1,Inventory:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:stone"}]}
```

And then this inverted to that command block.

```
/scoreboard players set @a eject 0
```

And added r=2 to the first part of execute command, it went exactly how Venya said.. It was only in a 2 block radius of the command block with the command.

So the execute command isn't correct.

Just tried this execute, works good so far. Waiting for a friend or two to test out the MP implications.  I think I am getting somewhere.

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @a[score_eject_min=1,score_eject=1,r=2] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[r=2,type=MinecartRideable]
```

Comment: "This is running on a SMP server with Forge and a few mods." Be aware that command mechanics rarely ever work outside vanilla. If you're experiencing oddities, I would recommend trying it in vanilla. If it works there, then it's Forge causing your problems.

Comment: I will try this in vanilla, but I am pretty sure the code is just not correct. I only started looking at Minecraft commands last week.

Answer (score 1):

you have just about everything you need, all you have to do is combine these commands:

```
/scoreboard players set @a InCar 1 {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable"}}}
/scoreboard players set @a InHand 1 {SelectedItemSlot:1,Inventory:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:stone"}]}
```

into:

```
/scoreboard players set @a eject 1 {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable"}},SelectedItemSlot:1,Inventory:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:stone"}]}
```

then every player that has a `eject` score of one (or more) is riding a minecart and has a stone selected in their hot-bar

if this doesn't help, let me know, I'll see what I can do

note: `~` in `/tp` teleports relative to the *player/entity*, `/teleport` is relative to the command block (or person executing)

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I will test this asap. Thank you Venya!

Comment: I still do think my failure will be with the /execute command.  I think i should add a radius to the player, and then again to the cart..  That may be the crux..  But the simplification of the scoreboard is gonna be perfect.